# looping with while statement

Tags: python

I've been trying to learn python recently.

One thing i've seen tutorials do is create loops by making a while statement with a variable that goes up at the end of each statement

example:

```
loop_end = 0
while loop_end <= 5:
    <do program>
    loop_end = loop_end + 1
```

This feels odd and a bit ugly.
Is there any other way to achieve this effect?

Comment: `loop_end += 1` if you still want while loop.

Comment: Provide links for these tutorials please? Some authors may need to be contacted...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#range

```
for i in range(6):
    # do stuff
```

Answer (score 3):

```
for loop_end in xrange(6):
    # do program
```

Answer (score 1):

You want the [range](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#range) function. Here's a loop that prints 0-2:

```
for x in range(0,3):
    print '%d' % (x)
```

Check [here](http://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop).

Range is exclusive, so the value on the right will never be met.

You can also denote how the range iterates. For example, specifying an increment of 2 each loop:

```
for x in range (0, 8, 2)
    print x
```

will get you

```
0
2
4
6
```

as an output.

Answer (score 0):

```
for loop_end in range(6):
    <do program>
```

Explanation:

Python has the concept of [iterators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator#Python%29). Different objects can decide how to be iterated through. If you iterate through a string, it will iterate for each character. If you iterate through a list (i.e. array), it will iterate through each item in the list.

The built-in `range` function generates a list. range(6) generates the list [0,1,2,3,4,5] (so is equivalent to `while loop_end <= 5`).

(In Python 3, range() returns a generator instead of a list, but you don't need to know that yet ;) ).